# Glade for Gtk 2 not work in ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am a new person in Glade GTK . I tried a working program (demo) in my Ubuntu using Python. But I got error message as

> File "revolution.py", line 21, in **init**
>       self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
>   glib.GError: revolution.glade: required gtk+ version 3.2, current version is 2.24

But I try much to install gtk+ verson 3.2 ... But no result.. Please advise me

Thanks
Anes

Comment: What do you mean by "try much"? Trying to upgrade the package using some kind of software center or `apt`, installing the newer version from source, ...? What exactly didn't work? Also, your title says Gtk 2, but the requirements you stated in the question are for Gtk 3.

Comment: Yea, I try to upgrade to version 3.2 , but get error messages. I try both option apt as well as from source... apt work full but not upgrade to new version. Still the same problem... any advise ?

Comment: It would be really helpful to include the error messages and your attempts into the question, like "I tried upgrading with this command and got this error". Also, can you include your Ubuntu version? Can you try searching for the package with `apt-cache search gtk+`? According to [this package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gtk%2B&searchon=sourcenames) Ubuntu should have newer packages, which generally isn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.04 and I think also 12.04, glade (supporting gtk3) and glade-gdk2 coexist.  So I thought it might be worth having a go at same on Ubuntu Mint 16.04 with default glade (3.18.3-1) installed.  On inspecting dependencies for both glade-gtk2_3.8.0 and glade 3.18.3-1, it appeared they were compatible.  glade-gtk requires libgladeui-1-11, glade 3.18.3- requires libgladeui-2-6.

So  I grabbed debs from trusty

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/glade-gtk2

https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgladeui-1-11

Seemed sensible to install the dependency first, so in my case (64 bit system)

```
sudo dpkg --install libgladeui-1-11_3.8.0-0ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb
```

followed by

```
sudo dpkg --install glade-gtk2_3.8.0-0ubuntu6.1_amd64.deb
```

Presto.  Both versions of glade in menus and functioning.

I locked both packages against updates.

Answer (score 0):

Was also getting the *required gtk+ version 3x, current version is 2x* error

The problem is that the newest version of Glade doesn't run with the default GTK version in Ubuntu.

I finally got it working by installing the older Glade V3.8.5  Note: I'm working on Xenial/16.04.

By installing the older version you can create Glade GUIs that run under GTK2.

Steps:

- remove the newer Glade (i.e. apt-get remove Glade) version
- download the V3.8.5 version of Glade (which is the last version to support GTK2) from:
  http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/glade/3.8/
- follow the install instructions (./configure, make, makeinstall)

I also needed to install these missing components (YMMV):

libgtk2.0-dev, intltool, libxml2-devel

It installed.  But... when I ran it.. it died:

glade-3: error while loading shared libraries: libgladeui-1.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

So finally I installed:  libgladeui*

Rebooted... voila.  Glade runs... the GUI I created works in Python2 (import gtk).